# Remove the previous and next element of the middle element in an array and shrik the array using Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an array say n elements
I put the array to an array list. And i find the middle index and remove the previous and next element of the middle element..

For instance if my array has 6 numbers
{1,2,3,4,5,6}
I find the middle element ie 4 and remove 3 and 5. Now my array should shrink and run the loop till the array gets empty. How do i do this?

**This is my code**

```
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
            int t=in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("t value"+t);
            int n=in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("n value"+n);

                int arr[] = new int[n];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                arr[i] =  in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("a[j]"+arr[i]);
                }
                ArrayList<Integer> obj = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                int count=0;
            for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
                obj.add(k,arr[k]);
            }
                //int m = in.nextInt();
                //System.out.println("m value"+m);
    for(z=0;z<n;z++){
          int middleIndex = (arr== null || arr.length == 0) ? 
        -1 : arr.length / 2; 
        System.out.println("middle"+middleIndex);
        obj.remove(middleIndex-1);
        obj.remove(middleIndex+1);
        --n;
    System.out.println(arr[z]);
        }
  }
}
```

**I get the following error:**

```
t value1
n value6
a[j]1
a[j]2
a[j]3
a[j]4
a[j]5
a[j]6
middle3
[1, 2, 4, 5]
middle3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:445)
    at TestClass.main(**.java:46)
```

And also here its removing my middleIndex-1 and middleIndex+2 element. I want to remove only the previous and next element of the array to be removed.

Comment: How do you decide that '4' is the middle element in a set with an even number of elements?

Comment: In Java you normally use Lists and other Collections instead of Arrays, especially if you have requirements like these. Is it possible in you project setting to use a `LinkedList`?

Comment: I see that you are calculating middleIndex out of arr.length, shouldn't you be using obj.length()? Also before removing objects from the list you need to make sure that they exist, otherwise you may get a nullpointer exception, for instance, when you have a list of size 2, you get the middle one and you try to remove middle +1 an -1, one of them wont exist for sure

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are removing elements from `ArrayList` variable `obj` whereas you are calculating the middle based on the `int` array variable `arr` which does not change in length after removal of elements. So in your example in the second loop the `middleIndex` is 3 but the size of `obj` is 4. now if  `obj.remove(middleIndex+1);` is called it means `obj.remove(4)` which throws the `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

Also there is a problem with your removal loop. You have used a new variable `z` it starts from 0 and continues to `n`, as shown in your example to 6 here. But the problem is that after the first loop the length of the `obj` is 4, after second loop the `obj` size is 2, and after 3rd loop the size becomes 0. so what is the utility of looping after that? would it not be better if

You could solve this by making a change as below:

```
while(obj.size()>0){
      int middleIndex = (obj.size() == 0) ? 
    -1 : obj.size() / 2; // replace the arr variable with obj. 
    System.out.println("middle"+middleIndex);
    obj.remove(middleIndex-1);
    obj.remove(middleIndex+1);
    --n;
    System.out.println(arr[z]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the size of the wrong object, you need to use `obj` instead of `arr`, and make sure the elements exist before trying to remove them.
Something like this would solve these problems:

```
 for(int z=0;z<n;z++){
     int middleIndex = (obj== null || obj.size() == 0) ?
          -1 : obj.size() / 2;
     System.out.println("middle"+middleIndex);
     if (middleIndex-1>0)
          obj.remove(middleIndex-1);
     if (middleIndex+1<obj.size())
          obj.remove(middleIndex+1);
     --n;
     System.out.println(arr[z]);
 }
```